# What are the tradeoffs involved in referencing Context in a library?

Tags: android, libraries

[`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is one of the core classes of Android, and many functions it contains are useful in Android library projects, particularly accessing configuration.  What are the trade offs involved in accessing the `Context` in a library, either by injection or by [subclassing `Application` in the library, and subclassing that in the application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7998222/16487).

Does this make the application brittle or introduce inappropriate coupling?

Comment: If you are referring to passing the Context to library functions or setting the Library's "Context" then this does not make the application/library brittle as it is common practice and is itself used by the android library, ie. for UI components